# How select cte update multiple tables column one time?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL script :

```sql
create table A 
(
    ID int,
    [Value] varchar(10)
);

create table B 
(
    ID int,
    A_ID int,
    Custom_value varchar(10)
);

with cte as 
(
    select * 
    from A 
    left join B on A.ID = B.A_ID
    where A.ID = '1111'
)
update cte 
set [Value] = 'v1', Custom_value = 'v2'
```

If only update A's `[Value]` it's ok, but when I want to update B's `Custom_value` at same time, I get this error:

> Msg 4405, Level 16, State 1, Line 67
> View or function 'cte' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables

I hope it's possible to update multiple table column at same time.

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  You can only update on table in an `update` statement.

Comment: Is it possible to do it by other way?

Comment: You can use multiple updates.  You can define a view with triggers on the view.

Comment: We can do insert, update, delete at all in one statement using MERGE. but we cant update in multiple table in single statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only update one table a time. Using cte or view does not change this. Update one table and then the other

```
update A set [Value] = 'v1' where A.ID = '1111';
update B set Custom_value='v2' where B.ID = '1111';
```

to avoid reading partially updated data, use transaction and appropriate isolation level